# Create an exception for database query timeout error

Tags: python, exception, flask, sqlalchemy

I have created a flask rest API,and i want to create an exception when app can not make connection to database (for example create a timeout error). My API is just a simple get request. How can i do that in Flask and Sqlalchemy?
My query is as follows:

```
response = Transactions.query.filter(
                    Transactions.id == requested_id).paginate(
                    1, 2, False).items
```

Comment: have you tried wrapping it in a try: except: block, or is there a reason you don't want to do that specifically?
you can catch a list of errors such as https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/errors.html#databaseerror

Comment: I used a try except but when the code comes to the query, it tries to connect to database constantly and doesn't create an error.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution for this?